# Gatsby blog how to add tags? following the gatsby docs to no avail

Tags: tags, gatsby, categories, gatsby-plugin, gatsby-plugin-mdx

I have recreated this blog template found here; https://github.com/gatsbyjs/tutorial-example

In my blog/index.mdx my fronmatter contains the following;

title:
date:
slug:
category:
tags:
hero_image:
hero_image_alt:
hero_image_credit_text:

My issue when following Gatsby docs on how to create tags page is I can't query frontmatter. I need some help creating the right file paths and creating a tags page.

Double points if you could only help me create a category page. I will have a small fixed amount of categories and wish to be able to link to them.

Many thanks. I am in a rush and have exhausted myself trying to understand...

I changed dirname to src/blog. did not work. Followed to gatsby docs for creating tags pages but couldn't query frontmatter...